# Interpreting lme4 fixed effects using pamer.fnc from LMERConvenienceFunctions package in R

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I'm fitting multi-level models in R using both `lme` from `nlme` package and `lmer` from `lme4`. It is a very simple model.

Using `lme`: `lmeModel <- lme(Flourish ~ Week * condition, random = ~ Week|id, na.action = na.exclude)`

Using `lmer`: `lmerModel <- lmer(Flourish ~ Week * condition + (Week | id), na.action = na.exclude)`

For each fixed effect, I get the same t-values, regardless of whether I use `lme` or `lmer`. Here's one of the fixed effects:

```
summary(lmeModel) #using nlme
Fixed effects: Flourish ~ Week * condition 
       Value Std.Error  DF  t-value p-value
Week 0.00570 0.1728345 569  0.03297  0.9737

summary(lmerModel) #using lme4
Fixed effects:
       Estimate Std. Error t value
Week 0.005698   0.172834    0.03
```

Someone has suggested that I use the `pamer.fnc` function from the `LMERConvenienceFunctions` package to run an ANOVA on my `lmerModel` to get the p values. Here is a section of the output for the same fixed effect:

```
pamer.fnc(lmerModel)
       Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value upper.p.val lower.p.val expl.dev.(%)
Week    1 49.7262 49.7262  5.0849      0.0244      0.0246       0.1043
```

Can anyone explain why the t-value of the fixed effect 0.03 (**p = 0.97**), which is not significant at all, but the F-value of the same fixed effect is 5.08 (**p ≈ 0.02**), which is significant? I really appreciate any help anyone can provide. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this is an interesting question, but hard to answer without a reproducible example.  (1) in general the F-statistic for a case with 1 denominator df should always be $t^2$, so I don't see where this F-value of 5.08 is coming from ... (2) lme is probably getting the denominator df for this random-slopes model wrong (but it might not make that big a difference (3) you can use the `lmerTest` package to get Satterthwaite or Kenward-Roger approximations for the p value ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I've just tried the `lmerTest` package and it reports the same p-values as the `lmeModel`, which means `lme` hasn't really got it wrong. I'm thinking the different p-value provided by `pamer.fnc` might be because it is related to F ratio, not t value. F ratios and their p-values are about variance explained, whereas t values and their p-values are testing whether the slope (beta values) differ significantly from 0. This is just my guess, so I'm not sure whether this explains the huge discrepancy in p-values.

Comment: I strongly suspect that `pamer.fnc` is doing something bogus but really can't tell without a reproducible example ...

Comment: So I shouldn't trust `pamer.fnc` and should just rely on the p-values provided by `lme` or `lmerTest`? It's difficult to provide a reproducible example, but I've uploaded the [data here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4o72k3mo6po0q66/MLMData.txt?dl=0).